# Database structure for Cocktail Recipes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

let me start by saying I'm a complete starter on SQL and MySQL, so decided to invest in this pet project to develop my database knowledge.

**Objective**: Build a very simple website to access a cocktail recipe database. The fields it has *id, name, glass, ingredients, method, ice, garnish, comment*.

It would be pretty simple for me if all the fields were linear but the ingredients column is cracking my head.

This is an example of a recipe:
[image: This is an example of a recipe:]

Some recipes may have 3 ingredients, some may have 5, others 10, and sometimes with different ways to measure those ingredients (ml, dashes, tsp, ...).

**My first question is**, *what's the simplest way to build a database like that? And how would I implement that?*

- Having all the ingredients separated by commas in the same column
- Creating one extra table for each recipe (can be more than 200 recipes)
- Creating one table with all the ingredients available in stock and then somehow connect them to the recipe table (many to many?)
- something else entirely

Having one table with all the ingredients would be interesting for future development for stock recording.

Since I'm upgrading from an pretty, ready to print, Excel sheet to sql database, **my second question is**, *What's the easiest/fastest method to move all the recipes to the database?* Again, I'll face a problem with the ingredients part.
Should I even try to export and import or just suck it up and input all the recipes by hand?

Thanks for reading and for any comment on the subject :)

Comment: Here's what I'd do: (1) Create a separate table called `ingredients`. (2) Create a new table `cocktail_ingredients` with a composite `UNIQUE KEY` of `cocktail_id` and `ingredient_id`. If you like, you could as well add the `proportion` column here. (3) Create a new table `recipe` that could describe the method. The combined relationship described between `ingredients`, `cocktails` and `recipes` is not very clear at the moment, so it won't be a good idea to comment on that right away. "Ingredients separated by commas in the same column" would only make life difficult - "normalise" instead.

Comment: A table of recipes, a table of ingredients, and a table saying what quantity of each ingredient belongs to each recipe

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that and report back in case i run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look into [database normalisation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) Essentially, it's the process of breaking up data into specific groups and then forming a new table with that data.

A few reasons to do is a) a good structure can make it easier to find, maintain, scale etc b) you want to repeat as little data as possible. If your database had one million records, you'd want to be as efficient as possible.

**Table 1:** 
ID (PK),Name,Method,Ice,Garnish,Comment

1
Cocktail Collins
Shake all ingredients...
Cubed
Lemon slice
For the elderflower...

**Table 2:**
ID (PK), T1_ID (foreign key), Ingredient, Quantity, Measure

row 1-

1: 1: Beefeater Gin: 2: tsp

row 2-

2: 1:Lemom Juice: 1: tsp

row 3-

3: 1: Sugar Syrup: 1: tsp

row 4-

4: 1: Soda 75: ml

Comment: Ok, so now I have this http://imgur.com/a/1mVPl .Follow up question: on the 'recipes' table, the columns 'quantity' and 'measure', is it possible to somehow have them dependent on eachother? My purpose being easy to convert for example oz into ml or other measurements. Or is that something I'd have to do client side?

Comment: Could you give another example? What do you mean? Do you mean when entering, for example, 1 measure will automatically enter 44ml?

Comment: I think I'm just over complicating it but yes, like you said, 1 measure of Gin would also be 25ml of gin and 1oz of gin. My goal was to have all the possibilities when displaying the recipe. The user would choose what unit system they would want the recipe display as.

Comment: The database only holds the data. If you wanted that, you could manually perform the calculation via PHP etc before adding the data. For example, calculate all your variables, and then insert the variables through your MySQL statement.